# About the intersection of the spectrum of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck by this exercise in my linear algebra book (undergraduate):

Lec $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Denote the spectrum of a matrix $M$ (the set of its eigenvalues) by $Sp(M)$. Let $\phi:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_n(\mathbb{C}):$

$$\phi(M)=AM-MB$$

Suppose $M\in \ker(\phi)$. In the previous exercises, I've proved that for all polynomial $P$, $P(A)M=MP(B)$, and when $Sp(A)\bigcap Sp(B)=\emptyset$, $\phi$ is bijective.

Now I'm asked to show that when $Sp(A)\bigcap Sp(B)\not=\emptyset$, $\operatorname{rank}(M)\le|Sp(A)\bigcap Sp(B)|$ and I'm stuck.

In the exercise to prove the bijectivity, I used an argument with characteristic polynomial, but it doesn't work here. I think I'm supposed to decompose $\mathbb{C}$ into 2 subspaces associated to eigenvectors, but I have no idea how to use the same eigenvalues as eigenvectors are different, would any one give me a hint? :)